# Sql only selects first row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a login database, and i have a number of users, when i attempt to log in with the user that is listed first in the database, it works perfectly. However, when i log in with another user, it doesnt work, it would appear that it will only select the first row. What is wrong with my query?

```
  $username = $_POST['Username'];
  $salt = substr($username, 0, 2);
  $password = crypt($_POST['Password'], $salt);

  $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
  $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `7Ducklings` WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?");
  $array = array($username, $password);
  $query->execute($array);
  $numrows = $query->fetchColumn();

  if($numrows == 1)
  {
    echo "success";
  }
  else
  {

  }
  $dbh = null;
```

Edit: on success when the     $numrows    are printed, i get 1, otherwise i get zero. Could it be a salt problem?

Comment: print_r your query result?

Comment: PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM `7Ducklings` WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ? )

Failed query

Comment: same thing on success too

Comment: first thing check the db connections in try catch, second try remove the symbol things from the table name `7Ducklings`.

Comment: Why using $numrows and fetchColumn() ? the name of the variable doesn't match the function return value... Try print_r($query->fetchAll())

Comment: Why "7Ducklings"? why not "user"?  **THANK YOU** for using prepared statements - you would not believe how many people are just blindly inserting into their DB with concatenated queries.  However... salts are supposed to be random, and unique - I guarantee that by using the first two characters of a username, this will not be enough (there's more info on Security.SE).  The salt is usually stored next to the password, so you need to hit the DB to retrieve it first (hmm, given the way modern password functions are supposed to work, I don't recommend doing the calc on the DB...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the if statement to check for Empty or TRUE/FALSE. fetchColumn() Returns a single column from the next row of a result set or FALSE if there are no more rows. [PDO FetchColumn](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

```
 $username = $_POST['Username'];
 $salt = substr($username, 0, 2);
 $password = crypt($_POST['Password'], $salt);

 $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
 $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `7Ducklings` WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?");
 $array = array($username, $password);
 $query->execute($array);
 $numrows = $query->fetchColumn();

 if(!empty($numrows))
 {
echo "success";
}
else
{

}
$dbh = null;
```